# Code to generate pdf from text in iphone

Tags: iphone, pdf

Can anybody tell me Code to generate pdf from text  in iphone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/RobertAPhillips/UIView_2_PDF

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reading the documentation that outlines this?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1